# MySQL: 'Subquery returns more than 1 row' during insert

Tags: mysql

based on my question above, below is my query:

INSERT INTO wla_crf_extend (bl_id, sap_crf_id) VALUES (4747, (SELECT id AS sap_crf_id FROM wla_sap_crf WHERE so_num = 2147480943))

When I run this query, will get this error, **Subquery returns more than 1-row**

the query from SELECT id AS sap_crf_id FROM wla_sap_crf WHERE so_num = 2147480943, actually will return more than 1 row.

Does anyone know whats the problem is? and how to fix it?

Comment: :Yes. Fix the subquery where it will only return one row with either a DISTINCT or a more exclusive WHERE clause. Clearly you can't insert multiple rows from the subquery into a single row's column with an INSERT. Please do yourself a favor and find a good basic SQL tutorial or book - learning those basics will save you a lot of frustration going forward. Just pounding the keyboard without really understanding what you're doing isn't going to get you very far.

Answer (score 1):

If your nested query (SELECT id AS sap_crf_id FROM wla_sap_crf WHERE so_num = 2147480943) returns more than 1 row then it means 'so_num' field isn't defined as 'unique', several entries in table 'wla_sap_crf' can have the same 'so_num' value.

You could either define 'so_num' field as UNIQUE or use another UNIQUE field that will actually return the precise row you want.

You could also use a combination of other fields in your query to produce the same effect if you don't know the identifier at the moment you make the query. IE: "SELECT id FROM students WHERE name='Bob' AND last_name='Ross' AND class=1".